# Use of Json extractor

Tags: jmeter, json-extract

Im running  a test plan containing 10 requests i need to get the variable value from 3rd response json  to be passed to request URL of 10 th request passed .  any way we can use json extractor to do this?

Answer (score 2):

This can be accomplished by using any of the post processors for correlation in amongst any of the requests. I have shown an example below with JSON Extractor

**Request Sample**

The value that I am going to extract from 3rd request's response is "I am the value to be fetched from 3rd response"

[image]

**JSON Extractor**

I am using the below syntax in JSON Path Expression to extract data from "valueToBeFetched" json object and storing it in variable named "extractedValue_C"

> $..valueToBeFetched

[image]

**10th Request**

Replacing the extracted value with syntax ${extractedValue_C} in 10th request

[image]

**Output**

Response Captured from 3rd Response

[image]

Captured value passed in 10th request

[image]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

JSON Extractor obeys [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide/) so if you put it as a child of the 3rd request - it will be applied to 3rd request only.

If you come up with a valid [JSONPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) matching the value you want to extract - the value will be saved into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) which can be used anywhere after 3rd request (where it is defined or overwritten in next iteration)